# Why can't I intersect these 2 objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've created these 2 objects and want to create a new object that represents the area where they intersect. I'm really confused as to why I cannot do it. I practiced on a cube and a cylinder in a new file and it work as expected. How do I find the issue with these objects?
[image]

You can check out [the file in question](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/310759/u/intersect_fail.blend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have doubles , flipped normals and ngons in your meshes.

Select the object named *mask*, enter edit mode and do the following :

-select all vertices , press <kbd>w</kbd> and *remove doubles*.
-recalculate normals with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

result :

[image]

Comment: You are a wizard! This really needs to be standard practice in all object creation. It was totally left out of the tutorial series I followed. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS